# Regex matches parts of a string, but not whole string

Tags: regex, match

This is the regex I'm using to validate a string that can contain lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers and dash:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9-])+$/
```

It has the following results:

- `abd` - matches
- `abcd-` - matches
- `abcd0` - matches
- `abcd0-` - matches
- `abc@` - doesn't match (correct)
- `abc@efg` - matches (incorrect, it shouldn't)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say you need `/^([a-zA-Z0-9-])+$/`. You want to match the whole string, not just a part, but **you're missing the mark for the beginning of the string `^`**.

`^` and `$` say *between the beginning and the end of the string* and `([a-zA-Z0-9-])+` says *there can be one or more characters `a-zA-Z0-9-`*.

Your regexp matches everything which contains one or more characters `a-zA-Z0-9-` before the end of the string no matter what's before.

You can test your regular expression on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jE8fA8/1) (very good online tool for regular expression testing with explanation, reference etc.).